# Does this graph depict a log scale?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

[image: is this a log scale?]

I'm a freelance editor and this graph is in a report and labeled as a log scale. (The version you see is my revision that removes the words "log scale".) 
The client insists that it is a log scale, it doesn't seem like that to me but then, I'm an editor and afraid of maths. 
If it makes any difference, the two quantities are indexed to each other where 2011 = 100.

Comment: A "log scale" graph has nothing to do with a particular shape, but refers to how the axis are graduated...

Comment: Thanks, Rahul. That was my thought but when there is an 'expert' telling you otherwise it's hard to remain sure.

Comment: were some comments deleted from here; why?

Comment: Comments about what?

Comment: there was a comment by Rahul answering the question, which is why I mentioned him in my reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a log scale.

Every time you go a certain distance upward, you **add** $20$.

On a log scale, every time you go a certain distance upward, you **multiply by** a particular number.

When you go from $100$ to $200$, you multiply by $2$.  When you go that same distance upward again, you'd multiply by $2$ again, getting $400$.  Then the same distance again and you'd get $800$, then the same distance again and get $1600$, and so on.

[image: Bitcoin prices on a logarithmic scale]

In this graph showing bitcoin prices as a function of time, every time you go from one of the horizontal lines up to the next, you multiply by $10$.